# Jquery function on parent dom object compile error with TypeScript

Tags: jquery, typescript

I'm having an error while compiling the following code located in a typescript file:

```
parent.$(mySelector)
```

Here I'm having an error on the $ sign who is unknown for the typescript compiler. Jquery is referenced through the definition file. What could I do to still be able to use this method of writing my code?

The proper error I'm having is the following:

```
The property '$' does not exist on value of type 'Window'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define $ variable for Window object, since JQuery definition file doesn't do that:

```
interface JQueryWindow extends Window {
    $: JQueryStatic;
}
```

and whenerver you use Window object cast it to JQueryWindow

```
(<JQueryWindow>parent).$(selector);
```

Comment: Further on this I got in another error:

    (<JQueryWindow>parent).$("").load(function (url, data, complete) { });  --> Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target


    (<JQueryWindow>parent).$("").each(function (index, elem) { return this; }); --> ok

Comment: i think problem is with load call. according to load signature its: load(url: string, data?: any, complete?: any): JQuery; so your call should be: (<JQueryWindow>parent).$("").load(url, data, complete); where url is the url you want to call, data is optional data you want to send and callback is a callback function that should be called when operation completes